# ezMark checkbox not checked by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the `ezMark` jQuery plugin for checkboxes, but when I try to check a checkbox using the following code, it is not working.

```
$('#chk').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Just to make sure, please add the link to the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to trigger the change event:

```
$('#chk').prop('checked', true).change();
```